# Reduce IO operations when reading/writing a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, file, io, disk

I am writing an automation that fixes/changes a lot of big CSV formatted files (the files are kept on an NFS server).

Most of my code works on the files in a row by row manner to avoid memory issues (even though the machines running my automation have relatively big Memory 100gb+)

I am trying to downsize on the IO operations on the NFS to avoid slowness and I am looking for a way to read the files in chunks rather than line by line.

Most of my read/write loops are implemented in the following manner (simplified for relevance):

```
    with open(path_to_old, "r") as old_csv, open(path_to_new, mode="w") as new_csv:
        reader = csv.DictReader(old_csv)

        writer = csv.DictWriter(new_csv)

        writer.writeheader()

        for row in reader:
            #run some checks/changes on row
            writer.write(row)
```

Is there an easy way to read/write chunks of predefined size (e.g: 10k rows/20 kilobytes at a time) into memory and working with them in a similar manner to csv.DictReader/Writer

Comment: Python file objects are already internally buffered by default. You can play around with that by checking out the `buffering` argument to `open`.  Check out `help(open)`,  [or the relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) so relevant: "buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy.
    Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select
    line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate
    the size of a fixed-size chunk buffer." So try with `buffering=20_000`

Comment: And also, check out what `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is on your system for some orientation